# ...のではない...がある sentence structure

Tags: meaning

> 現場に行くのではない支援がある

I sometimes get tripped up with ではない ("it isn't" vs. "isn't it?"). In the above sentence, I'm guessing the meaning is "I have support that isn't making it to the site", but I have a feeling I may have a skewed understand and would appreciate anyone's opinion on the actual meaning, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us with the context? Is this a kind of slogan?

Comment: 現場に行くのではない means 現場に行かない

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any further context, this phrase *probably* means "There's a kind of support that doesn't require you to go to the site." Or it may have a stronger and paradoxical meaning: "You can support by *not* coming to the site."

This would make sense when one wants to euphemistically say "Indirect support like donation is also welcome." or "Ill-prepared volunteers who rush to the disaster site [may do more harm than good](http://jp.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052702303570604580076623331110444)."